# Javascript - Using a slidebar to expand a div or table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, border, containers, expand

Is it possible to have a div or table column expandable by the user when he or she clicks on a border of one of the containers and moves it left or right. Kind of like when a user clicks on a horizontal scroll bar and moves it.

Comment: Whenever I read "Is `x` possible?" questions, I'm inclined to answer, "Nope, it's impossible." The real question should always be "How do you do `x`?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked the [jQuery UI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) plugin ?

Comment: I ran past this but I didn't think it had what I needed, but at closer glance I see it's what I need. Thanks man